# making nonexact equation exact; getting wrong answer

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following ODE but keep getting the wrong answer. It's not exact but I make it exact:
$(2y^2+3x)dx+2xydy=0$ make it exact by multiplying by x to give
$(2y^2x+3x^2)dx+2x^2ydy=0$

$M=2y^2x+3x^2$ and $N=2x^2y$
$M_y=4yx$ and $N_x=4xy$ therefore it's now exact :)

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y^2x+3x^2$
$\int 2y^2x+3x^2dy=\frac{2y^3x}{3}+3x^2y+g(x)$
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(\frac{2y^3x}{3}+3x^2y+g(x))=\frac{2y^3}{3}+6xy+g'(x)$ which is equal to N

$\frac{2y^3}{3}+6xy+g'(x)=2x^2y$
$g'(x)=2x^2y-6xy-\frac{2y^3}{3}$
$g(x)=\frac{2x^3y}{3}-\frac{6x^2y}{2}-\frac{2y^3x}{3}$
simplyfying I get $\frac{4}{6}x^3y=C$ but that's not what the back of the book has

Comment: @bof yep...fixed it. Typing out so much is very error prone.

Comment: Why don't you make life easier using $y^2=z$ since the ODE contains $y^2$ and $2y\,dy$ ?

Comment: On line 5, your $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2y^2x+3x^2$ should be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2y^2x+3x^2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you make it exact, you should go:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=2y^2x+3x^2$$

and

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=2x^2y$$

Comment: ah crap I got the $\partial x$ and $\partial y$ switched around